# How can we implement tracking mode on Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, currentlocation, mkusertrackingmode

When I try to implement user tracking mode(like ios) on google map, the mode tracks to user we she/he moves along way, I could not find any documentation on its official side.Which method provides like picture2?

My map's settings as below code snippet

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    this.googleMap = googleMap;

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
}
```

When I triggers to focus on user current location

```
//there exist current Location
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLatitude,currentLongitude),16));
```

The output behaves like picture 1 , not picture 2.

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQm5B.png)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYhSD.png)

Comment: You mean the heading vector?

Comment: I mean when user change his/her location while tracking or driving , his/her blue dot follow him/her along way.It's term is tracking mode on iOS maps. When I googled heading vector, I could not find any example ? @Raptor